# How to concatenate same attribute values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<Remittance>
  <R A01="R" A02="14155304" A03="36132.49" A04="" A05="36132.49" A06="" A07="" />
  <N A01="N" A02="Hi" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" />
  <N A01="N" A02="This" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" />
  <N A01="N" A02="is" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" />
  <N A01="N" A02="concat" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" />
</Remittance>
```

I looking to concatenate all `A02` attribute values of element `<N>`

Expected result : "HiThisisconcat"

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use [**`string-join()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join):

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(//N/@A02, '')"/>
```

to return

```
HiThisisconcat
```

as requested.

Comment: sorry in my machine it will support only XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `string-join()`, you could use `<xsl:value-of select="//N/@A02" separator=""/>`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-value-of

> If the separator attribute is present, then the effective value of
>   this attribute is used to separate adjacent items in the result
>   sequence...

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//N/@A02">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you don't have any templates that would otherwise match on these attributes, you could also just use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//N/@A02"/>
```

To ensure that no other templates would match, you could create a template with a mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="N/@A02" mode="concat">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//N/@A02" mode="concat"/>   
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```